# Error using subprocess.check_output in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am at a very basic level in Python, and I'm trying to learn how to use the subprocess module.  I have a simple calculator program called x.py that takes in a number, multiplies it by 2, and returns the result.  I am trying to execute that simple program from IDLE with the following two lines of code, but I get errors.  The number 5 is the number I'm trying to feed into x.py to get a result. Would someone mind helping me understand what I'm doing wrong and help me get it right?  Thanks!

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.check_output(["C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Desktop\\x.py",5])

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
result = subprocess.check_output(["C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Desktop\\x.py",5])
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 855, in _execute_child
args = list2cmdline(args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 587, in list2cmdline
needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `5` as a string:

```
import sys
result = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Desktop\\x.py", '5'])
```

Comment: I tried passing 5 as a string, and I received a new, fun error!

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    result = subprocess.check_output     (["C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Desktop\\x.py",'5'])
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in       _execute_child
    startupinfo)
   WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: @Thetravellingfool Try my updated solution, and make sure you've added `python` to the `path` environment variable settings.(`C:\\Python27`)

Comment: I appreciate your help! I added Python to the path environment variable settings and used the code you suggested, and it gave me another wonderful error. Any thoughts?

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
  result = subprocess.check_output ([sys.executable, "C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Desktop\\x.py", '5'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
  raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
  CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Python27 \\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Desktop\\x.py', '5']' returned  non-zero exit status 1

Comment: @Thetravellingfool Is that script working fine when executed through cmd?

Comment: Yes, I opened the cmd prompt and typed in python C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\x.py and my script ran.  It asked me for a number, I supplied it, and it returned an answer.  What do you think is up with the non-zero exit status 1 error?  Thanks!

Comment: @Thetravellingfool It's hard to say anything without looking at the actual script, BTW if you're passing the number `5` as command line argument then use `sys.argv` to catch it, no need to use `raw_input` there.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I will start another question with my scripts and the latest error message.  Cheers!

Comment: @Thetravellingfool You can [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to mark this question as solved.